# SharePoint 2013 - User Profile Pictures does not replicate to AD using Profile Synchronization

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile-service, user-profile-property, ad

I am working with SP 2013 Intranet Site.

I am working on a issue where I can upload a photo to User My Site and it gets replicated to AD and then to Outlook. However, existing photos in User MySites does not get replicated to AD.

I have verified permissions on AD and everything seems normal. The Export Synchronization process is working from SP to AD. But existing pictures residing in MySites user profiles does not get exported to Thumbnail property in AD. I ran MIISClient.exe to see if there are any export errors but I could not see any errors being reported.

What steps should I take to resolve this issue. Thanks.

Thanks,

Amit

Answer (score 1):

Lets talk about how we can get a picture in user’s My Site to be synchronized with Active Directory (AD) and hence other applications like Outlook or Lync (formally office communicator) can utilize it.

So lets get started with assuming –

1)“User Profile Synchronization Service” is in “Started” state on appropriate SharePoint server

2)“Replicate Directory Changes” permission on a domain is present for synchronization account http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh296982.aspx#RDCdomain

3)If you will export property values from SharePoint Server to AD DS, the synchronization account must have Create Child Objects (this object and all descendants) and Write All Properties (this object and all descendants) permissions on the organizational unit (OU) that you are synchronizing with. Ref: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff182925.aspx#permission

4)You have a functional SharePoint 2010 / SharePoint 2013 environment which is configured to do Profile Synchronization. For more details on this please refer to http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff382639.aspx
Currently this is how the picture space in Outlook and Lync shows up for our example user Amy Alberts.

For more information click on below links :

> [Sync my site image to AD](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/nishants/2012/02/21/how-to-sync-picture-from-sharepoint-to-active-directory-and-hence-to-outlook-and-lync/)

Comment: The export sync process is working for new photos uploaded to MySites and it get synced to AD. So, it means there are no issues with permissions. Only existing photos on Mysites does not get synced to AD and to outlook. How would I ensure existing picture in MySItes get synced to AD. It seems SP marked existing profile pictures in the database with some flag and does not include these pictures in the export sync process.